# What kind of hash does mysql use?

Tags: mysql, hash, passwords

I'm writing my own code similar to phpMyAdmin. But I'll need the user to be able to sign on using their username and password from the mysql database. I need to know what kind of hash the mysql database uses to store each users password. I checked dev.mysql.com for answers but couldnt find anything, other than its the newer 41 byte hash beginning with an *.

Comment: When you send the password to mysql, you send it in cleartext, you don't need to hash it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to decrypt password stoed in MySQL table and it's of no use using password which is stored in `mysql`.`user` table.

You should be using password that is being set when `User` is created in your application, If you have lost password of users then you can reset it using `mysqladmin`

> SET PASSWORD FOR 'user-name-here'@'hostname-name-here' = PASSWORD('new-password-here');

Answer (score 3):

Not sure, what exactly your question is aiming at, but if you want to know how MySQL encrypts passwords stored in the user table read [here in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-names.html):

> MySQL encrypts passwords stored in the user table using its own
>   algorithm. This encryption is the same as that implemented by the
>   [PASSWORD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password) SQL function but differs from that used during the Unix
>   login process. Unix password encryption is the same as that
>   implemented by the [ENCRYPT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html#function_encrypt) SQL function. See the descriptions of the
>   [PASSWORD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password) and [ENCRYPT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html#function_encrypt) functions in [Section 12.13](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html), “Encryption and
>   Compression Functions”.
>
> From version 4.1 on, MySQL employs a stronger authentication method
>   that has better password protection during the connection process than
>   in earlier versions. It is secure even if TCP/IP packets are sniffed
>   or the mysql database is captured. (In earlier versions, even though
>   passwords are stored in encrypted form in the user table, knowledge of
>   the encrypted password value could be used to connect to the MySQL
>   server.) [Section 6.1.2.4, “Password Hashing in MySQL”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/password-hashing.html), discusses
>   password encryption further.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL 4.1+ uses a double [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) hash (With the inner hash outputting raw data, not hex), the older versions seems to use a non-standard hash.

(There are PHP implementations of both in the [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766978/mysql-password-function-to-php))

Unless you have a good reason to use them (compatibility with MySQL passwords / legacy code seems to be the only good reasons), you should be using bcrypt / PBKDF2  / scrypt for hashing passwords.