# Using PHP to compare MySql Password()

Tags: php, mysql, passwords

I have found this post helpful [MySQL password() function to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766978/mysql-password-function-to-php) but I am having trouble applying the solution offered there to my problem.

A password was stored in a Mysql using `Password()`. I want to adapt this script to compare the entered password with the one stored in the database, rather than use the 'crypt()' function.

```
    public function authenticate($user,$pass) {
        $mysqli = new mysqli(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS,DB);
        if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        error_log("Cannot connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
        return false;
        }
        $safeUser = $mysqli->real_escape_string($user);
        $incomingPassword = $mysqli->real_escape_string($pass);
        $query = "SELECT * from users WHERE username ='{$safeUser}'";
        if (!$result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
            error_log("Cannot retrieve account for {$user}");
            return false;
        }

        // Will be only one row, so no while() loop needed
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $dbPassword = $row['password'];
        if (crypt($incomingPassword,$dbPassword) != $dbPassword) {
        error_log("Passwords for {$user} don't match");
        return false;
        }
        $this->id = $row['id'];
        $this->firstName = $row['first_name'];
        $this->lastName = $row['last_name'];            
        $this->username = $row['username'];
        $this->email = $row['email'];
        $this->dateJoin = $row['dateJoin'];
        $this->school = $row['school'];
        $this->level = $row['level'];
        $this->isLoggedIn = true;
        $this->_setSession();
        return true;
    } //end function authenticate
```

Is there an easy way to adapt this script? Do I just add

```
AND `password` = PASSWORD('{$incomingPassword}')
```

to my query? This seems a little clumsy.

Comment: You need to be using prepared/parameterized queries.  Otherwise you are wide open to SQL injection attacks, and your code randomly failing when folks use apostrophes and what not.

Comment: `real_escape_string` is perfectly sufficient against SQL injection.

Comment: You should see the "note" in the manual for the password function: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password I would recommend using the `crypt` function and storing the resultant hash in the database. You can use salting techniques and other better methods as well.

Comment: yes, you can just use 'AND `password` = PASSWORD('{$incomingPassword}')' to where clause.  or you can use build-in md5 function, like " where `password`=md5('{$incomingPassword}')"

Comment: MD5 is not recommended to use as a password storage method. @PaulManning It's considered too fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you really sure the passwords where hashed with the MySql `Password()` function, because this function is [not meant to be used in applications](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password)? It is **not** possible to store passwords safely and verify passwords in an SQL-query directly.

You really should use a slow hashing function like BCrypt, and salting is mandatory. That means, that you need a two step process, first get the stored password hash by username with an SQL-query, then extract the salt from the hash and do the verification.

The recommended way to hash passwords with PHP is the new function [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php):

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

If you are interested in more in-depth information about this topic, you can have a look at my [tutorial](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php) about safely storing passwords.

Comment: Thanks for your response and excellent tutorial pitched right at my level!